# href for link in google maps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, google-maps, rails-geocoder

I use `geocoder` in my app and to show the markers on the map, using `json`.
it look like this:

```
... 
$.get("get_organizations.json", function( data ) {
        $.each( data, function( index, organization ) {
            var organizationLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng( organization.latitude, organization.longitude );
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: contentString});
            var contentString = organization.title;
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: organizationLatLng,
                map: map,
                title: organization.title
            });
```

and all works fine, but I want to link in `infowindow` and need solution in this question!
if I change value of `contentString`, I don't know what should be in `href` of link

```
var contentString = '<a href="???">' + organization.title + '</a>';
```

link should redirect to the selected organization in `infowindow`!
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you have a REST route and the relative path to an organization looks like `/organizations/1234` where `1234` it is `id` of organization:

```
var orgId = organization.id;
var orgTitle = organization.title;
var contentString = '<a href="/organizations/' + orgId +">' + orgTitle + '</a>';
```

Comment: Couldn't find Organization with 'id'=undefined

Comment: looks like your `get_organizations.json` response doesn't included organization `id`.